# lapply error - PGLS (caper) with multiples comparative.data

Tags: r, lapply

i need help in the following problem.

I generated a list containing 1000 `comparative.data`and i want to run 1000 `pgls` using each of these `comparative.data`. I tried to use `lapply` function for this, using the following code:

```
pg <- lapply(obj, function(z){pgls(formula = y ~ x, cd[[z]], lambda = "ML")})
```

`obj` is a list of 1000 `data.frames` with my data. `cd` is my list of 1000 `comparative.data`.

When i tried to run this code the followin error returned:

```
 Error in pgls(formula = y ~ x, cd[[z]], lambda = "ML") : 
  object 'z' not found
```

I can not see where is the error's source

Thanks in advance

---

**More informations**

`obj` is used to generate the `comparative.data`. To generate the 1000 `comparative.data` using the 1000 data frames in `obj` list, i used:

```
cd <- lapply(1:1000, function(x) comparative.data(phy = phylogeny, 
                                            data = as.data.frame(obj[[x]]), 
                                            names.col = species_name,
                                            vcv=T, vcv.dim=3))
```

To run one `pgls` for the hundredth `comparative.data` the code is:

```
mod <- pgls(formula = y ~ x, cd[[100]], lambda = "ML")
```

---

**Calling the hundredth `obj` and hundredth `cd`**

```
obj[[100]]
# A tibble: 136 x 3
# Groups:   Binomial, herbivores [136]
   Binomial                            herbivores      tm
 * <chr>                                    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Abies_alba                                 30. 0.896  
 2 Abies_balsamea                              2. 0.990  
 3 Abies_borisii-regis                         1. 0.940  
 4 Alcea_rosea                                 7. 0.972  
 5 Amaranthus_caudatus                         1. 0.173  
 6 Amaranthus_hybridus_subsp._cruentus         1. 0.310  
 7 Aquilegia_vulgaris                          9. 0.365  
 8 Arabidopsis_thaliana                        8. 0.00280
 9 Arabis_alpina                               2. 0.978  
10 Ariocarpus_fissuratus                       1. 0.930  
# ... with 126 more rows


cd[[100]]
Comparative dataset of 136 taxa:
Phylogeny: tree 
   136 tips, 134 internal nodes
   chr [1:136] "Mercurialis_annua" "Manihot_esculenta" 
"Malpighia_emarginata" "Comarum_palustre" ...
VCV matrix present:
   VCV.array [1:136, 1:136, 1:16] 61.9 189.3 189.3 189.3 189.3 ...
Data: as.data.frame(obj[[x]]) 
   $ herbivores: num [1:136] 4 1 1 5 19 21 7 4 4 2 ...
   $ tm        : num [1:136] 0.516 0.915 1.013 0.46 0.236 ...
```

Comment: How does `pgls` use *obj*? Please show a correct call on one data frame and one *comparative.data*.

Comment: I added informations to the above problem, i hope i have made it clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since *cd* was created from *obj*, there is no need to reference *obj* in `lapply` call but simply pass your list of *comparative.data* which you can do by object:

```
# BELOW d IS DATA FRAME OBJECT PASSED INTO LAPPLY LOOP
pg_list <- lapply(cd, function(d) pgls(formula = y ~ x, d, lambda = "ML"))
```

Or by index:

```
# BELOW i IS INTEGER VALUE PASSED INTO LAPPLY LOOP
pg_list <- lapply(seq_along(cd), function(i) pgls(formula = y ~ x, cd[[i]], lambda = "ML"))
```

---

Alternatively, you can combine both `lapply` calls, assuming you do not need the intermediate object, *cd* list, for other purposes:

```
# BELOW x IS OBJECT PASSED INTO LAPPLY LOOP
pg_list  <- lapply(obj, function(x) {    
                   cd <- comparative.data(phy = phylogeny, 
                                          data = as.data.frame(x), 
                                          names.col = species_name,
                                          vcv=T, vcv.dim=3))

                   pgls(formula = y ~ x, cd, lambda = "ML")
            })
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much